# Entering Data Based on other lists Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, scripting, google-sheets

We are attempting to set up a custom Google Script to assist in the day to day with the Business Office. Currently they are wanting something that will enter a job code but will allow teachers to enter a name (such as Track and it be translated to 5506). I am having issues with getting it to work and it will not pull the codes over and enter them into the Spreadsheet. I am currently just working with Google Scripts to write these custom methods. See below to see what I currently have.

```
function changeCodes(input, names, codes)
{
  var outputArray = [];
  var found = new Boolean("false");
  for(var i = 0; !found; i++)
  {
    if(input.equals(nameArray[i]))
    {
      outputArray.push([codes[i].getValue()]);
      found = new Boolean("true");
    }
  }
  return outputArray[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in working on it further I found that what I thought I was saying wasn't quite true. In calling everything properly it does work properly. This works similar to VLOOKUP however with this you are able to set what it references as the intake, what it compares it to, and what it outputs more fully than with VLOOKUP.

```
function changeNames(input, names, proper)
{
  var outputArray = [];
  var found = false;
  for(var i = 0; !found; i++)
  {
    if(input.equals(names[i]))
    {
      outputArray.push(proper[i]);
      found = true;
    }
  }
  return outputArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using associative array.

```
function test2() {
  Logger.log(getCode("Job2"));
}

function getCode(input) {
  var code = {
    "track": 5506,
    "job1" : 5510,
    "job2" : 5520 }
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  if (input in code) {
      return code[input];
  } else {
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: That certainly helps and it should help to get me in the right direction. However we are hoping to pull an array from a Google Sheet so that they can continually update the array. (I know I just made it ridiculously harder but that is what my boss is wanting). Thank you for your help that may help me get on the right track.